# How can I plot a temperature field on gnuplot from data file?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with 3 columns: x,y coordinates and the third with the temperature (T column) in each point. I want to plot in 2D with differents color  from low to high temperature. The data file is like:

```
x   y   T
1   1   12
1   2   15
1   3   34
2   1   45
2   2   15 
2   3   12
3   1   34
3   2   09
3   3   02
```

Answer (score 0):

For a heat map you must change the format of your data file slightly. The parts with different x-values must be separated by a single empty line. Using the following file `data.dat`:

```
1   1   12
1   2   15
1   3   34

2   1   45
2   2   15 
2   3   12

3   1   34
3   2   09
3   3   02
```

You get a nice plot with the script

```
set autoscale fix
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set palette rgb 21,22,23

plot 'data.dat' with image notitle
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the option *every ::1* you can skip the first line (with the header).
With the version of gnuplot I used it was not needed to modify the data adding the empty lines (even if it is good practice to do it).

```
set autoscale fix
set xtics 1 
set ytics 1

set palette defined ( 0 "black", 1 "red",  2 "orange" )
plot 'data.txt' every ::1 using ($1):($2):($3) with image notitle
```

Plot generated with gnuplot 4.6 
[image]